# RemoveClass not working on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently have a dynamically dropdown menu which uses `<select>` and converts them into a `<ul><li>`. Once you click on any of the list item elements, it adds a class called `.selected` to the item.

**What i want to achieve?** Once you start hovering over the list items, it should a class to the `<ul>` called `.hovering`.

**Problem:** When a user clicks on the `document`, `window`, clicks off dropdown or selects another dropdown, the class `.hovering` should remove from the `<ul>`. This is all happening apart from the when the user selects an item, it closes the dropdown but the hovering class is not removed.

```js
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
(function(jq) {

  jq.fn.selectBox = function() {

    // Cache the number of options
    var sthis = jq(this),
      numberOfOptions = jq(this).children('option').length;

    // Hides the select element

    if (jq('html').hasClass('touch')) {

      jq('.options').addClass('s-hidden');

      sthis.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
      // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
      sthis.wrap('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');


    } else {

      sthis.addClass('s-hidden');

      // Wrap the select element in a div
      sthis.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

      // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
      sthis.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

      // Cache the styled div
      var styledSelect = sthis.next('div.styledSelect');



      // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
      var slist = jq('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
      }).insertAfter(styledSelect);

      // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        jq('<li />', {
          text: sthis.children('option').eq(i).text(),
          "data-value": sthis.children('option').eq(i).val(),
          "class": sthis.children('option').eq(i).attr('class'),
          "data-sku": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('sku'),
          "data-stock": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('stock'),
          "data-backorder": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('backorder'),
          "data-preorder": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('preorder')
        }).appendTo(slist);
      }

      // Cache the list items
      var slistItems = slist.children('li');

      slistItems.hover(function() {
        slist.addClass('hovering');
      });



      // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)

      styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var closeClicked = jq(this).hasClass("active");

        jq('div.styledSelect.active').each(function() {
          slist.removeClass('hovering');
          jq(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();

        });

        if (!closeClicked) {
          jq(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
        }
      });


      // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
      // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
      slistItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        styledSelect.text(jq(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        jq(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
        sthis.val(jq(this).data('value'));
        sthis.addClass('THIS');
        slist.removeClass('hovering').hide();
      });


      // Show the first select option in the styled div
      if (sthis.val()) {
        var currentSelect = sthis.find("option:selected").val();

        styledSelect.text(sthis.find("option:selected").text());

        slist.find("li[data-value='" + currentSelect + "']").each(function() {
          jq(this).addClass('selected');
          slist.removeClass('hovering');
        });

      } else {
        styledSelect.text(sthis.children('option').eq(0).text());
      }


      // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
      jq(document).click(function() {
        styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        slist.removeClass('hovering').hide();
      });
      jq('#addtoBag, .wishListBtn').click(function() {
        styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        slist.removeClass('hovering').hide();
      });
    }


  };

}(jQuery));

jq('.selectBoxStyle').selectBox();
```

```css
.selectSizeMain {
  width: 56.77966%;
  float: none;
  margin: 2.1875rem auto auto;
}
.s-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-family: GibsonRegular, HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: .875rem;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
.styledSelect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.styledSelect:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: 9px;
}
.styledSelect.active:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: 9px;
}
.options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: white;
}
.options li {
  padding: 11px 13px;
  margin: 0 0;
}
.options li:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.options li.selected {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selectSizeMain">
  <select class="selectBoxStyle">
    <option value="">Choose Size</option>
    <option value="aye">Aye</option>
    <option value="eh">Eh</option>
    <option value="ooh">Ooh</option>
    <option value="whoop">Whoop</option>
  </select>
</div>
<select class="selectBoxStyle">
  <option value="">Month&hellip;</option>
  <option value="january">January</option>
  <option value="february">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
  <option value="april">April</option>
  <option value="may">May</option>
  <option value="june">June</option>
  <option value="july">July</option>
  <option value="august">August</option>
  <option value="september">September</option>
  <option value="october">October</option>
  <option value="november">November</option>
  <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only handled adding the class on mouseenter. But i don't see any method for removing it.

```
  slistItems.hover(function() {
    slist.addClass('hovering');
  }, function(){
    slist.removeClass('hovering');
  });
```

`hover()` in jquery is like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` combined into one, where the first event is the `mouseenter` and the second is `mouseleave`. So...

```
if (jq('html').hasClass('touch')) {

  jq('.options').addClass('s-hidden');

  sthis.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
  sthis.wrap('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');


} else {

  sthis.addClass('s-hidden');

  // Wrap the select element in a div
  sthis.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

  // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
  sthis.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

  // Cache the styled div
  var styledSelect = sthis.next('div.styledSelect');



  // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
  var slist = jq('<ul />', {
    'class': 'options'
  }).insertAfter(styledSelect);

  // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    jq('<li />', {
      text: sthis.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      "data-value": sthis.children('option').eq(i).val(),
      "class": sthis.children('option').eq(i).attr('class'),
      "data-sku": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('sku'),
      "data-stock": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('stock'),
      "data-backorder": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('backorder'),
      "data-preorder": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('preorder')
    }).appendTo(slist);
  }

  // Cache the list items
  var slistItems = slist.children('li');

  slistItems.hover(function() {
    slist.addClass('hovering');
  }, function(){
    slist.removeClass('hovering');
  });

  ...
```